# Deleted Answer Should not Appear On the Top

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, sorting

Is it possible to sink my own deleted answer to the bottom?

Sometimes, in the case of a vote tie, the deleted answer will be ranked at the top (for example, for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463987/execute-sql-query-from-sql-file) I deleted one of my duplicated answer)

It is best if you can always assign the lowest priority ( regardless of votes) to the deleted answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago, answers sort by accepted (if not self-accepted), score, and deleted questions at the end.  Apologies this question was never updated, going through and leaving updated info on these now.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, but so few people see them that I don't think it matters.

Answer (score 2):

Since only you (and moderators) can see the deleted answers, this really only affects your view, correct?

Comment: And 10K+ users.

Comment: Of course, 10k users have probably implicitly accepted the quirks...

Comment: I thought (erroneously?) that >10k rep == moderator?

Comment: Moderator = one who has a little ♦ after their name. 10k+ users have more privileges than lower-rep users, but are still limited.

Comment: aha. That clears that up :)